# Catch is executed when .then operation is successful

Tags: node.js, callback, response, knex.js

```
db('fruit').where('fruit_name', 'apple')
    .then(data => {
      if (data.length === 0) {
        db('fruit').insert({
          amount: '2'     //just for this post
        })
          .then(res.sendStatus(200))
          .catch(res.sendStatus(500));
      }
      else {
        db('fruit').where('fruit_name', 'apple').update({
          amount: '5'    //just for this post
        })
          .then(res.sendStatus(200))
          .catch(res.sendStatus(500))
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.sendStatus(500)
    })
```

I don't understand why the catch block is being executed and the server gave me the `Can't set header after sending them` error. This error occur because I am sending two res.sendStatus. The .then block are working fine and .catch block should not be executed unless the data fails to store in DB.

This is written in knex.js in a Node Express server and for just in case, the query statement is querying the fruit table where fruit_name column's item is equals to apple, insert new amount row if apple doesn't exist else if exist update the amount row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db('fruit').where('fruit_name', 'apple')
.then(data => {
  if (data.length === 0) {
    db('fruit').insert({
      amount: '2'     //just for this post
    })
      .then(()=>res.sendStatus(200))
      .catch(()=>res.sendStatus(500));
  }
  else {
    db('fruit').where('fruit_name', 'apple').update({
      amount: '5'    //just for this post
    })
      .then(()=>res.sendStatus(200))
      .catch(()=>res.sendStatus(500))
  }
})
.catch(error => {
 return res.sendStatus(500)
})
```

Hi calvert. You need to return your responses.This should work fine now.

Comment: Awesome, it works but I thought res.sendStatus will send the status back to the front end? It wasn't sending back  the response if I exclude the ()=> ?

Comment: "The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise." Please read more here: 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then